# Unable to retrieve name from ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I am trying to retrieve the NameId from the JWT Claims Identity which is set when the user on my app registers/logs in. The method below keeps returning null and I have no idea why:

```
var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByUsernameAsync(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);
```

Here is the GetUserByUsernameAsync method within the user repository:

```
 public async Task<AppUser> GetUserByUsernameAsync(string username)
        {
            return await _context.Users
            .Include(user => user.Photo)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(user => user.UserName == username);
        }
```

I have checked the value of the 'username' that is passed into the method above by setting up breakpoints and checking the value of this argument when the method is called. This is how I know it is returning null.

This the token service which is used to create the token when the user registers:

```
namespace api.Services
{
    public class TokenService : ITokenService
    {

        private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _key;

        public TokenService(IConfiguration config)
             _key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"]));
        }
         public string CreateToken(AppUser user)
        {
           var claims = new List<Claim>  
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, user.UserName) 
            };

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(_key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);


            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor 
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims), 
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
                SigningCredentials = creds 
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler(); 

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
}
```

The token is attached to the header using an interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private databaseService: DatabaseService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let currentUser: User;

    this.databaseService.currentUser.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => currentUser = user);

    

    if(currentUser) { 
      request = request.clone({ 
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
        }
      })
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

This interceptor has been added to the providers array in the app.module file:

```
 providers: [HttpClientModule, 
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true},

  ],
```

Edit: I know the NameId is correctly being set when the user registers as I have setup breakpoints and checked the values when I test the register user functionality

Edit: I have added the startup config files below (this is an extension method which is then used in the startup file):

```
namespace api.Extensions
{
    public static class IdentityServiceExtensions
    {
         public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) 
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) 
             .AddJwtBearer (options => 
             {
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters 
                 {
                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                     
                     
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"])), 
                    ValidateIssuer = false, // This is the API server
                    ValidateAudience = false // This is our angular app


                 };
             });

             return services;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of the startup file:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.AddApplicationServices(_config);
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "api", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddCors();

             services.AddIdentityServices(_config); 
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see `two things missing` first, in your ***backend ASP***  -  Your startup code is missing I would guess you are missing the setup, see below. Second, in your ***frontend Angular Step 4*** and below you need to add it to your header in your app.module.ts

> BACKEND ASP

1. First off you have to *setup the startup configure services*, setup the `UserIdClaimType` on the server side inside your `Startup.ConfigureServices:`.

---

```
   services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => 
     options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

---

2. Second, *the next two `steps 2, 3` allow you setup custom claims* you need to clear and then map it in your token handler /
   service, do the the following next two steps to allow Microsoft Identity to override any claim/names you plan to use

---

```
   // in the API startup or where ever you are handling the token setup
      JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); just before the app.UseAuthentication()
```

---

3. Then remap whatever claim name/type you are planning to use

---

```
var id = this.User.FindFirstValue("myCustomClaim");
```

> FRONTEND ANGULAR

4. Add this to the app.module.ts in your angular the imports

```
JwtModule.forRoot({config: {tokenGetter}... and the rest of whatever needs to be setup

export function tokenGetter() {
   return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it necessary to include the JwtModule.forRoot in the app.module file even when I am using an interceptor? I didn't include the configuration setup code but I have updated the OP now.